# undefined method - geoBoundingBoxQuery(String location)

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a `geoBoundingBoxQuery("pin.location")` in Java for Elastic Search. Eclipse is not able to resolve imports for this method although the Elastic Search Java API documentation specifically suggests to use this method.

What class do I need to import which has this method?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-geo-queries.html#java-query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having the same issue, I have found the answer.

Its the version of Elastic search java API that I am using is the issue. The documentation is for version 2.1 whereas I am using an older version. For the older version, you need to do the following:

`FilterBuilders.geoBoundingBoxFilter("pin.location")`

Answer (score 0):

`geoBoundingBoxQuery("pin.location")` is defined as a static method in class `org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders`, so you can use it this way:

```
QueryBuilder q = QueryBuilders.geoBoundingBoxQuery("pin.location");
```

Elasticsearch documentation is assuming you're using a static import like:

```
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.geoBoundingBoxQuery;
```

so you don't need qualify the method with class name:

```
QueryBuilder q = geoBoundingBoxQuery("pin.location");
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work. QueryBuilders.geoBoundingBoxQuery() is not found. Maybe because of the older version that I am using. Thanks for your input though.